# How can I improve this snooker scoring app?

Tags: javascript, numbers, calculator

I am building a simple snooker scoring app. How could I write this code in a more fluent way?

Also - how would I put a limitation on the number of times a ball can be clicked and the max points that could be scored (147 - 15 reds with 15 blacks and all the colours after this)?

E.g. 15 reds begin on the table with 6 other colours. Once a red is 'potted', there is a choice of playing any other colour (red then yellow, red then blue, red then black etc). Once those 15 reds have been cleared only the colours should remain and then no ball allowed to be clicked after the final ball (black) has been 'potted'.

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eg8Lm267/

```
    const redBall = document.querySelector('.red');
    const yellowBall = document.querySelector('.yellow');
    const greenBall = document.querySelector('.green');
    const brownBall = document.querySelector('.brown');
    const blueBall = document.querySelector('.blue');
    const pinkBall = document.querySelector('.pink');
    const blackBall = document.querySelector('.black');
    const score = document.querySelector('.score');
    
    let scoreVal = 0;
    score.innerHTML = scoreVal;
    
    redBall.addEventListener('click', () => {
      scoreVal++;
      score.innerHTML = scoreVal;
    });
    
    yellowBall.addEventListener('click', () => {
      scoreVal += 2;
      score.innerHTML = scoreVal;
    });
    
    greenBall.addEventListener('click', () => {
      scoreVal += 3;
      score.innerHTML = scoreVal;
    });
    
    brownBall.addEventListener('click', () => {
      scoreVal += 4;
      score.innerHTML = scoreVal;
    });
    
    blueBall.addEventListener('click', () => {
      scoreVal += 5;
      score.innerHTML = scoreVal;
    });
    
    pinkBall.addEventListener('click', () => {
      scoreVal += 6;
      score.innerHTML = scoreVal;
    });
    
    blackBall.addEventListener('click', () => {
      scoreVal += 7;
      score.innerHTML = scoreVal;
    });
```

Comment: Seems better suited at [codereview.SE]

Comment: You've got a lot of repetition in the code. Try getting rid of it.